# How to create dynamic query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 7 records. 6 of them have `selling` and 1 is `rent`. In array i get this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Selling"
  1 => "Rent"
]
```

But when i foreach that in result i get 4 and not 7. Any suggestion how can i fix this. Im trying to create dynamic query so if i enter one more thing that i dont need to change here anything.

```
if(is_array($option)){
    foreach($option as $o){
        $q->orWhere('name', 'like', $o);
    }

  }
   else{
      $q->orWhere('name', 'like', $option);
   }
```

Comment: It looks like what you have should be working properly. It looks like you may have duplicate `whereOr` parts, but in this case it doesn't seem like it would be the problem. What does the rest of your query look like? Could you include whats going on before and after the example you have in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loop, use `whereIn()`

```
if(!is_array($option)){
   $option = [$option];
}
$query->whereIn('name', $option)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's array_unique to be sure there are no duplicate options.

```
if(is_array($option)) {
    $option = array_unique($option); // remove any duplicate options
    foreach($option as $o){
       $q->orWhere('name', 'like', $o);
    }
}
else{
    $q->orWhere('name', 'like', $option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **LIKE** in your query, it will be better to write like this

```
if(is_array($option)){
    foreach($option as $o){
        $q->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$o.'%');
    }

  }
   else{
      $q->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$option.'%');
   }
```

otherwise it will search the exact names